# Searching the first field and getting the output of all records where the first field is the same.

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a pretty big text file. This file contains words and a number of definitions given for the words. There are 60 words which are repeated 17 times. The words are always in the first field and the definitions in the following fields adjacent to the words.

Example:

```
hand;extremity of the body;that which is commonly used to write with

paper;thin sheet made of wood pulp;material used to write things on;some other def's

book;collection of pages on a topic;publication of knowledge;concatenated paper with text

ham;that which comes from pork;a tasty meat;a type of food

anotherword;defs;defs;defs;defs
```

it continues until it reaches the 60th word then restarts with the same 60 words and different definitions. The order isn't always the same so the next 60 might be

```
book;defs;defs;defs

television;defs;defs;defs

ham;defs;defs;defs;defs;defs

paper;defs;defs
```

the field separator for this file is ";" and there is a empty record in between each record as shown in the examples.

What I want  to do is look at the first field and output  the records with the same first field. 
Example:

```
ham;defs;defs;defs;defs;defs
ham;defs;defs;defs
ham;defs;defs;defs;defs
ham;defs;defs;
ham;defs;defs;defs
ham;defs;
ham;defs;defs
ham;defs;defs;defs;defs
paper;defs;defs;defs;defs
paper;defs;defs;defs
paper;defs;defs;
```

and so on.

I apologize if this isn't clear. Please help!

Comment: If I say you want to sort your file based on first word of the line and ignore all the blank lines...is that correct ? Just trying to understand your requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple grep and sort command can that for you... try as below....

## Explanation:

```
# ^$ will search for blank lines and -v will reverse that search ... so you get all lines which has data
# passing that data to sort command will sort it... 
# -t option of sort for delimiter and -k option take which column it need to sort

grep -v ^$ yourfile.txt | sort -t";' -k1

# And if you expect duplicate lines also, meaning same lines multiple time but need it only 1 time... then pipe to the uniq command as below

grep -v ^$ yourfile.txt | sort -t";" -k1 | uniq
```

For your sample data I get the output as below....

```
$ grep -v ^$ mysamplefile.txt | sort -t";" -k1 | uniq
anotherword;defs;defs;defs;defs
book;collection of pages on a topic;publication of knowledge;concatenated paper with text
book;defs;defs;defs
ham;defs;defs;defs;defs;defs
ham;that which comes from pork;a tasty meat;a type of food
hand;extremity of the body;that which is commonly used to write with
paper;defs;defs
paper;thin sheet made of wood pulp;material used to write things on;some other def's
television;defs;defs;defs
```

Comment: `sort` may give unexpected results for words that share a common prefix.  Consider, for example, input with three lines: "ham;abc",
"ham;xyz", and "hamilton;def".  `sort` may place the line for "hamilton" in the middle of the two lines for "ham".

Comment: Thanks @john1024, modified the command to consider the delimiter also while sorting